# Is it possible to force Excel to only read/save files from/to a particular folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I press Save as... in Excel, it's possible for me to navigate anywhere on my computer or network in order to decide where to save my spreadsheet.

Due to company restrictions, we need to pinpoint an exact folder where saving/reading is allowed and nowhere else. Is it somehow possible to do this from an Excel point of view? I know I can set NTFS permissions on folders and such, but as Excel runs as the logged in user, other aspects of file handling will then be negatively impacted.

UPDATE:

If it was possible to set NTFS in such a way that file/folder deletion wasn't possible without also affecting file renaming, then this Excel redirection hack wouldn't be needed. But as NTFS cannot be configured appropriately, I need to find a workaround in order to secure data integrity. Clarification: the forced folder is a place where files can be deleted at wish. But anywhere else, delete must not be possible.

Comment: So what will prevent a user from copying a saved file elsewhere? And how does this differ from saving the file there in the first place?

Comment: Good, thx for asking @cybernetic.nomad. We're using kiosk software to restrict the users to only being able to use Excel once logged in (Windows 7/10).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is beyond the scope of Excel but here is my thought:

Could you create and log in using an account that only has full control to a certain folder? It can have reading access to everywhere else.

Also, if you want to allow an user to rename file, it means you are allowing them to delete a file and create same file with different name. Therefore, that user must have both delete and create permission.

Comment: Sorry, but the login requires full access to the file system. The kiosk software also mandates the permissions of the logged in user (we only have one account) to be that of an administrators. When using Excel however, we would like to lock things down.